# AnyLogic - modeling large number of different ResourcePools

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent

I would like to model a larger number of employees (about 30) as a resource pool. Each employee is given parameters before the model starts, which the simulation end user can enter manually. Each employee has different working hours (shift work, different on each day of the week), different duration of the shift and different tasks assigned to them.

My first thought was to model each employee individually as a resource with their own shift schedule. That would be easiest, but I bet there is a nicer solution - anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your workers have different settings such as different shift hours, they will not belong to the same `ResourcePool`.
You must build an agent that contains a ResourcePool (so that you can use it as a resource) with its another parameters such as capacity etc.

In my opinion, the most correct thing is to build a `Population` of them. Each item in the population is an amount of workers with identical parameters.

Comment: Hey Yossi, don't know if I'm following you tbh. I understand your suggestion. But how exactly could I implement it in my model? How could I e.g. use this type of population in a size-block? You have to choose from which resourcePool you want to take workers. Would be very kind of you to help me out here! :)